# Snap to Grid and Absolute Grid Snap not working as expected

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to work with a rectangular mesh and I've been using Snap to Grid and Absolute Grid Snapping but I've noticed some of the snapping doesn't snap where I expect and seems to be dividing the grid by 2.

I am working in blender 3.3LTS and I have changed the following settings:
In Scene, Units is set to None
Viewport Overlays Subdivisions are set to 16 from the default 10
Snapping Mode is set to Increment with Absolute Grid Snap enabled
The move/transform coordinate space is set to Global

Here are some images to explain what I'm seeing.
I select the piece of the mesh I want to move/alter:
[image]

I press G while holding Ctrl and instead of snapping to the grid it snaps the vertices to the centers of each grid square:
[image]

Further movement leads to proper snapping by the increment, just not on the grid:
[image]

Of additional note, the snapping works as expected if I only select a single vertex or a line segment that is parallel to the orthographic camera perspective(so it appears as a vertex from that angle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the tool tip for the *Absolute Grid Snap* says in the first screenshot of the answer by @L0Lock, the snapping is based on the **pivot center**. So you can change what is snapping to the grid by changing the pivot center, for example to *Active Element*. This way you can use a vertex in *Vertex Select* mode or an edge in *Edge Select* mode for snapping:

[image: active element pivot]

Example for the active vertex snapping to the grid:

[image: vertex snapping to grid]

Or, if you want it vertically centered, you can use an active edge to have its center snap to the grid:

[image: actve edge to grid]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was missing. I noticed after I posted that it was only present when the mesh was oddly divisible by the subdivisions so I figured it was some kind of centering thing.

Comment: Ooooh I misunderstood the tooltip as meaning it would always use the center of selection x) Nice!

Answer (score 1):

> I press G while holding Ctrl and instead of snapping to the grid it snaps the vertices to the centers of each grid square:

Actually, it does snap to the grid. But from the center of your selection, not from a specific vertex:

[image]

Not sure whether there's a way around it.

You could use the addon [CAD Transform for blender 3.x](https://blender-archipack.gumroad.com/l/nQVcS). It's only for version 3.x, but as "pay what you want" pricing, whereas [the update for 4.x is paid](https://blender-archipack.gumroad.com/l/emiwtw).

With it, you can toggle the CAD transform tool, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> select its vertex and grid snapping options:

[image]

Then press <kbd>G</kbd> to start moving, click a vertex to snap from, optionally press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to toggle between local and global grid, and click where you want to snap to.

[image]